# Maven error in Eclipse when including aws-java-sdk-acmpca

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, aws-sdk

Whenever I add the dependency below, I get this error in Eclipse: *Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project. Could not initialize class okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-acmpca</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.994</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried adding it to its own project with no other dependencies and I still get the same error so I don't think that a dependency is clashing with anything else. Is it possibly caused by okhttp's move to Kotlin? More importantly, how do I move past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by updating my version of Eclipse. The version that had the issue (for me) is Release 4.16 (2020-06). I updated to Release 4.19 (2021-03) and everything works now.